# How to add an image to canvas, and put a rotated text on top of it?

Tags: html5-canvas

Im trying to get canvas to work, what i'm trying to do is make an image(from an existing image) and place a text on it. I want the text to be rotated on the left side of the image. The moment i try to rotate the text, i can't see it anymore in the canvas. Im using the following solution:

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
ctx.save();
ctx.rotate(-0.5*Math.PI);
ctx.font = "12px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
ctx.fillText("copyright", 0, 0);
ctx.restore();
var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
```

With this solution i cannot see the text anymore. When i delete the rotation and make the code into the following, everything works fine the image is rendered and the text is rendered on the image.

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
ctx.rotate(-0.5*Math.PI);
ctx.font = "12px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
ctx.fillText("copyright", 0, 0);
var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
```

Can anyone see the mistake im making, or does someone have a solution to this problem of mine?

[edit]
I've made a jsfiddle showing the problem http://jsfiddle.net/7kzuN/4/

Comment: Can u make a fiddle outta this?

Comment: I've made the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7kzuN/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Before rotating you should always set the rotation point.**

Think of the rotation point as a pencil-tip pressed on on a piece of paper.

When you rotate, the paper will rotate around the point of the pencil-tip.

You set the rotation point using context.translate(x,y).

To rotate on the left side of the image, you would translate something like this:

```
// set the rotation point

ctx.translate(6,img.height/2);
```

This sets your rotation point 6 pixels off the left side and at the vertical-center of the image.

Here's example code and a demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/ANpPm/

[image]

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

var img=new Image();
img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/houseIcon.png";
function start(){
    canvas.width=img.width;
    canvas.height=img.height;
    // draw the image
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    // save the unrotated context
    ctx.save();
    // set the rotation point with translate
    ctx.translate(6,img.height/2);
    // rotate by -90 degrees
    ctx.rotate(-0.5*Math.PI);
    // draw the copyright bar
    ctx.fillStyle="black";
    ctx.fillRect(-img.height/2,-6,img.height,14);
    ctx.font = "12px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
    ctx.fillText("copyright", -img.height/2+5,-6);
    // restore the context to its unrotated state
    ctx.restore();
    // save the image+text to a dataURL
    var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

}
```